# Iterator should return strings, not bytes (the file should be opened in text mode)

Tags: python, django, excel, sqlite, csv

List item

this is my code..

```
def import_excel(request):

  if request.method == 'POST':
    person_resource = PersonResource()

    dataset  = Dataset()
    new_person = request.FILES['myfile']
    if not new_person.name.endswith('csv'):
      messages.info(request,'Wrong format')
      return render(request,'upload.html')
    
    imported_data = dataset.load(new_person.read(),format='csv')
    for data in imported_data:
      value = Person(
        data[0],
        data[1],
        data[2]
      )
     value.save()
  return render(request,'upload.html')
```

while importing the csv file to the database  getting the error:

> iterator should return strings, not bytes (the file should be opened in text mode)

like this

This is my model...

```
class Person(models.Model):
  name    = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  marks   = models.IntegerField()
  def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

This is the csv file
[image: This is my csv file..]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please fix the indentation of the code so that we have a proper [mre] (currently, the line `value.save()` doesn't line up with anything else, so it will cause an `IndentationError` as is, and it isn't clear how you intended it to be placed). Please try to make sure that someone else can **copy and paste all the code from the question, without changing or adding anything**, to see the problem - directly (i.e., without waiting for the program to do anything else, or having to click buttons etc.), and exactly.

Comment: Also, please make sure to show [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error messages when asking for help with an error. For Python code, this means: **copy and paste, starting from the line** that says `Traceback (most recent call last):` until the end, and format it like multi-line code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the data of the uploaded file as follows and the problem will be solved.

```
new_person = request.FILES['myfile'].read().decode("utf-8")
```

According to the model you don't have an ID, just make the following changes to log in

```
for data in imported_data:
  value = Person(
    data[1],
    int(data[2])
  )
 value.save()
```

But if you want to have an ID in the model, then you must change the model as follows and write the loop as follows (of course, you must have values in the ID column in the CSV file)

```
class Person(models.Model):
  id      = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
  name    = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  marks   = models.IntegerField()
  def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

loop try this

```
for data in imported_data:
  value = Person(
    int(data[0]),
    data[1],
    int(data[2])
  )
 value.save()
```

Comment: it solved but another one  error is  came::  str' object has no attribute 'name'

Comment: plz put here output of this added command line print(new_person) after this line new_person = request.FILES['myfile']  - Error is for new_person.name.endswith('csv')

Comment: imported_data = dataset.load(new_person.read().decode("utf-8"),format='csv')  i used like this  im getting error Field 'id' expected a number but got ''.

Comment: Well, it is better to get an output from the imported_data variable to determine what the structure is, then read it according to the structure and enter it in the model. You probably need to convert some values to the corresponding data type in your model, for example, integer or string.

Comment: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'swamy'. finally im gettin like this

Comment: plz could u resolve this

Comment: I need to know the structure of the model and CSV file, please edit and put these items in the description of the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251298/discussion-between-swamy-patel-and-amin-zayeromali).